# Seeking for a general method to turn the term(s) in a formula into a list

Tags: functions, functional-style

If we want to make arbitary formula into a List, for example, input (1+a^3) and we want the output data to be {1,a^3}, we can use List@@(expr). However when input data becomes a^3, we need to change the code into List@(expr), otherwise we will get {a,3}.

But turning a formula into a list is just a internal process so I don't know if the formula is of one term or a polynomial of many terms. I need a general method to turn any expanded formula into a list.

Thanks a lot for reading my question and sincerely hope you can offter a helping hand.

test data:

1. input (1+Sqrt[a*b]+a^2*b^3), output {1,Sqrt[a*b],a^2*b^3};
2. input (a^3), output {a^3};
3. input((x+y)(z+y)), output {x z,x y, y z,y^2}

Comment: `f[expr_] := If[Head[expr] === Plus, List @@ expr, {expr}]` test with `f /@ {1 + a^2*b^3, a^3}`

Comment: what is the desired output for `(x + y)^2`? Is it `{x^2, y^2}` or `{x^2, 2 x y, y^2}`?

Comment: Amazing! Thank you very much!@Bob Hanlon

Comment: I hope the output can be {x^2, 2 x y, y^2} @kglr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:**

```
ClearAll[f]
f = Replace[ExpandAll@#, Plus -> List, 1, Heads -> True] &;

f /@ {1 + a^2*b^3, a^3, (x + y)^2, 1 + Sqrt[x y] + (x + z)^2}
```

> ```
> {{1, a^2 b^3},
>  a^3, 
>  {x^2, 2 x y, y^2}, 
>  {1, x^2, Sqrt[x y], 2 x z, z^2}}
> ```

**Original answer:**

If the input expression is a polynomial [`MonomialList`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MonomialList.html) gives the desired output:

```
MonomialList /@ {1 + a^2*b^3, a^3, (x + y)^2}
```

> ```
>  {{a^2 b^3, 1}, {a^3}, {x^2, 2 x y, y^2}}
> ```

If you need the terms in a specific order use the third argument of `MonomialList`:

```
monomialList = MonomialList[#, Variables @ #, "NegativeLexicographic"] &;

monomialList /@ {1 + a^2*b^3, a^3, (x + y)^2}
```

> ```
> {{1, a^2 b^3}, {a^3}, {y^2, 2 x y, x^2}}
> ```

Comment: Thank you very much for your elegant and succinct answer!

Comment: I'm sorry to bother you again, but it seemingly doesn't works for polynomial with terms of noninteger power, and my formula also include terms like Sqrt[a b]

Comment: @babyblue, unfortunately, `MonomialList` works only for polynomial input.

Comment: Yes, I see. I'm very appreciated for your help anyway.

Comment: @babyblue, please see the update.